# Why are there 2 windows on my app? I'm using ttkbootstrap

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

I'm creating a small app that just gets jokes from an API using ttkbootstrap. The problem is there are 2 windows showing when I run the app. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```py
import requests
import ttkbootstrap as tb
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

def get_joke():
    url = "https://icanhazdadjoke.com"
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    joke_time = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json().get('joke')
    label.config(text=joke_time)
    print(joke_time)

label = tb.Label(text="", font=("Poppins", 16), bootstyle='default')
label.pack(padx=5, pady=10)
btn = tb.Button(text="Get Joke!", command=get_joke)
btn.pack(padx=5, pady=10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = tb.Window(themename='darkly')
    app.title('Joke App')
    app.geometry('1280x900')
    app.mainloop()
```

Here is a screenshot of what's happening
[image: double window on tkinter ttkbootstrap]

Comment: When you create the label `label`, an instance of `Tk` will be created implicitly.

Comment: @acw1668 this is worth an answer if you cannot find an existing duplicate Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a master to your label and button. Example:

```
import requests
import ttkbootstrap as tb
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

def get_joke(label):
    url = "https://icanhazdadjoke.com"
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    joke_time = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json().get('joke')
    label.config(text=joke_time)
    print(joke_time)

def start(master) -> None:
    label = tb.Label(master, text="", font=("Poppins", 16), bootstyle='default')
    label.pack(padx=5, pady=10)
    btn = tb.Button(master, text="Get Joke!", command=get_joke(label))
    btn.pack(padx=5, pady=10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = tb.Window(themename='darkly')
    app.title('Joke App')
    app.geometry('1280x900')
    start(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Edit:

If you want to button to actually work, then you need to use lambda and a text variable for the label, like so:

```
import requests
import ttkbootstrap as tb
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

def get_joke(label_text):
    url = "https://icanhazdadjoke.com"
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    joke_time = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json().get('joke')
    label_text.set(joke_time)

def start(master) -> None:
    label_text = tb.StringVar()
    label = tb.Label(master, textvariable=label_text, font=("Poppins", 16), bootstyle='default')
    label.pack(padx=5, pady=10)
    btn = tb.Button(master, text="Get Joke!", command=lambda: get_joke(label_text))
    btn.pack(padx=5, pady=10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = tb.Window(themename='darkly')
    app.title('Joke App')
    app.geometry('1280x900')
    start(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: so you mean the button doesn't work if not for the lambda?

Comment: Didn't on my computer.

Comment: huh? It worked on mine

Comment: what is the master for?

Comment: @VicenteAntonioG.Reyes Master is the frame or window you want to add your label and button.

Comment: can you point me to the docs where I can study what that means?

Comment: @VicenteAntonioG.Reyes The official tkinter documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter.Tk.master